# How to highlight tree view sections of admin sidebar menu using javascript?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have built a sidebar menu using Bootstrap 4:

[image: Sidebar Menu]

Here is the code for that sidebar:

```
<li class="treeview">
        <a class="app-menu__item" href="#" data-toggle="treeview"><i class="app-menu__icon fa fa-users"></i>
            <span class="app-menu__label">Users</span>
            <i class="treeview-indicator fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li>
                <a class="treeview-item d-flex justify-content-between"
                   href="{{ route('admin.users.index') }}"
                   rel="noopener noreferrer">
                    <span>All Users</span>
                    <span class="badge badge-primary mr-2">{{ $users_all}}</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

And here is the jquery code:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var treeviewMenu = $('.app-menu');

    $('[data-toggle="sidebar"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    $('.app').toggleClass('sidenav-toggled');
    });

    $("[data-toggle='treeview']").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('is-expanded')) {
            treeviewMenu.find("[data-toggle='treeview']").parent().removeClass('is-expanded');
        }
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('is-expanded');
    });
})();
```

How can I highlight the sections in the tree view after clicking on them?

I can check the url for each section in the menu, but I want to automate highlighting sections as it will be updated in the future.